# get month year from a given date

Tags: perl

I have a file that has a list of dates. I want to get the information of Month Year. I was doing the following: (I omit the part of open a file)

```
 $request_date = "2012-01-02 08:12:11";
 chomp(my $monthdatefile = `date '+%B %Y' --date='$request_date'`);
```

but it takes too much.

From Unix will be that what I want:

```
   $ date '+%B %Y' --date='2012-01-02 08:12:11'
   January 2012
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $request_date = '2012-01-02 08:12:11';

my $tp         = Time::Piece->strptime($request_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
my $month_year = $tp->strftime('%B %Y');

print $month_year;
```

**output**

```
January 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about speed, I'd just have a hash table of 12 entries for months. 
Then extract the fields as follows:

```
my %hash = (1 => 'January', 2=>'February', ...);

$request_date =~ /^(\d+)-(\d+)-/;
my ($year,$month) = ($1,$2);
print $hash{$month}." ".$year;
```

Comment: Don't try to optimize for performance unless there's actually a performance issue. The Time::Piece solution is easier to maintain and significantly more flexible. Also, your hash keys need to begin with `0` when less than 10 (e.g. `'01' => 'January'`) to match the OP's date format.

Comment: Your argument about maintainability and flexibility is debatable. But you're right about '01', which you can also easily fix by $hash{int($month)}.

Comment: Say the OP decides they want to output the day of the week as well (e.g. `Tuesday`)? With Time::Piece, that's a 2-character change (add `%A` to the `strftime` format string); in your solution, not so simple. That is just one of *many* examples I can come up with.